# How can I publish a port in a gitlab-runner?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I want to deploy a container on my server with gitlab-runner (docker executor) and then get response from my local browser.

I have the most simple dockerfile that start an nginx:

```
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY /nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
EXPOSE 80
```

And my nginx config looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }

}
```

Here's my .gitlab.yml:

```
image: docker:latest
services: 
  - docker:dind

variables:
  WORK_DIR: ${CI_PROJECT_NAME}
  BRANCH: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}
  REGISTRY: registry.gitlab.com/myusername/cicdtest

stages:
  - build
  - deploy

build_project:
    stage: build
    script:
        - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
        - docker build -t $REGISTRY .
        - docker push $REGISTRY



deploy_project:
    stage: deploy
    script:
        - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
        - docker pull $REGISTRY
        - docker stop $(docker ps -a -q) || true && docker rm $(docker ps -a -q) || true
        - docker run --name=$BRANCH -p 80:80 -itd $REGISTRY
```

And my config.toml:

```
[[runners]]
  name = "name1"
  url = "https://gitlab.com/"
  token = "secret"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "docker:alpine"
    privileged = true
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache", "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"]
    shm_size = 0
```

By the way everything with docker and nginx works fine in localhost.

Now when I push to repo all the pipelines get the passed status and every line is executed fine but when I try to access my container from my local browser with url **185.xxx.xx.xx** I can't get any responses. It's like gitlab-runner didn't publish any ports.

Answer (score 0):

At first, please inspect the running Docker container and see if your idea, that the ports are not set up correctly, is right:

```
[docker inspect [OPTIONS] NAME|ID [NAME|ID...]]
```

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/inspect/